# Which wheel has most chance of winning a roulette game?

Tags: probability

Player A get to choose the first wheel. Player B must choose a wheel from the 2 others.

Both players spin their wheel.

Just in case the image doesn't work :
$$\text{wheel 1 }( 3,4,8 )$$
$$\text{wheel 2 } ( 1,5,9 )$$
$$\text{wheel 3 } ( 2,7,6 )$$

First off, I figured there are $3^3$ possibilities.
Then I went and wrote down each possibilities...

I have that the first wheel has a 8/27 chance to win
wheel 2 has 11/27
wheel 3 has 8/27.

So player A has an advantage if he chose wheel #2.

Is it the right way to solve this problem ? Was I suppose to use the choose or permutation notation ?

Edit : The player that spins the highest number win the game.
This is a fictive game.

Edit2 : For example, player A decide to choose wheel 1. Player B then choose wheel 3.
Player A spin his wheel and get 4. Player B spin and get a 7.
Player B wins.

Comment: I think some information is missing, maybe because I don't know the game of Roulette. What numbers are winning numbers?

Comment: Sorry I realise I forgot to mention that the player with the highest number win the game. I will edit my post.

Comment: The totals of all wheels equal 15, and with minor rearrangement the "wheel" entries are columns of the classic magic square known as the [Lo Shu diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo_Shu_Square).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just need to patiently calculate probabilities. It will take a while. But you will be doing most of the work.  And the final result will be **very** interesting. To read much more about the proble, look at the Wikipedia article on [Non-transitive Dice.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice)

**Case 1:** Suppose that player A chooses wheel $1$.  Let us see what B should do.

Suppose that B chooses wheel $2$. what is the probability that B wins?

Maybe A's wheel will produce a $3$. That has probability $\frac{1}{3}$. **Given** that A's wheel produces a $3$, with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ B's wheel produces a higher number, so she wins.

Maybe A's wheel will produce a $4$. That has probability $\frac{1}{3}$. *8Given** that this happened, again, with probability $\frac{2}{3}$, B wins.

Maybe A's wheel will produce an $8$. That has probability $\frac{1}{3}$. Then with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, B wins.

So **if** A chooses wheel $1$ **and** B chooses wheel $2$, the probability B wins is $$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{9}.$$

Suppose that now that A chooses wheel $1$ and B chooses wheel $3$. The same sort of calculation shows that the probability B wins is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{0}{3}=\frac{4}{9}$.

So it is clear that **if A chooses wheel $1$**, then B should choose wheel $2$ to maximize her probability of winning. And her probability of winning will be bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$. that is, B will have an edge.

**Case 2:** Suppose A chooses wheel $2$? What should B do? What is B's probability of winning if she chooses wisely?  You can do the calculations. You will find that in that case, B should pick wheel $3$, and that if she does, she will have probability $\frac{5}{9}$ of winning.

**Case 3:** Suppose A chooses wheel $3$? What should B do?  Again, you can do the calculations.

**Remark:** After you do the calculations, you will notice that **whatever** choice A makes, B can choose a wheel that on average will beat A.  This is a very surprising result: In a sense, wheel $2$ is "better" than wheel $1$.  And wheel $3$ is better than wheel $2$. But wheel $1$ is better than wheel $3$!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pit each wheel against each of the others.

Suppose that Player A chooses the first wheel and Player B the second. The $3^2=9$ (equally likely) possible outcomes are $\langle 3,1\rangle,\langle 3,5\rangle,\langle 3,9\rangle,\langle 4,1\rangle,\langle 4,5\rangle,\langle 4,9\rangle,\langle 8,1\rangle,\langle 8,5\rangle$, and $\langle 8,9\rangle$. Player A wins $4$ of them, and Player B wins $5$.

If Player A chooses the first wheel and Player B the third, on the other hand, the outcomes are $\langle 3,2\rangle,\langle 3,7\rangle,\langle 3,6\rangle,\langle 4,2\rangle,\langle 4,7\rangle,\langle 4,6\rangle,\langle 8,2\rangle,\langle 8,7\rangle$, and $\langle 8,6\rangle$, and Player A wins $5$ of them. Thus, if Player A chooses the first wheel, Player B should choose the second, and Player A’s probability of winning will be $\frac49$.

You only have to work out one more calculation like this, for the second wheel against the third, and you’ll be able to figure out what happens if Player A chooses the second wheel or the third.

Answer (score 2):

here is how I see it.

**wheel 1 vs. wheel 2**

if wheel 1 rolls 3, chance of winning is 1/3

if wheel 1 rolls 4, chance of winning is 1/3

if wheel 1 rolls 8, chance of winning is 2/3

probability that wheel 1 beats wheel 2 is therefore 4/9

**wheel 1 vs. wheel 3**

if wheel 1 rolls 3, chance of winning is 1/3

if wheel 1 rolls 4, chance of winning is 1/3

if wheel 1 rolls 8, chance of winning is 3/3

probability that wheel 1 beats wheel 3 is therefore 5/9

**wheel 2 vs. wheel 3**

if wheel 2 rolls 1, chance of winning is 0/3

if wheel 2 rolls 5, chance of winning is 1/3

if wheel 2 rolls 9, chance of winning is 3/3

probability that wheel 2 beats wheel 3 is therefore 4/9

**conclusion**

we have a "rock paper scissors" situation where wheel 1 beats wheel 3 beats wheel 2 beats wheel 1, all with probability 5/9. Therefore  player B has an advantage,but needs to choose the wheel that beats the wheel player A picked.